# required and found error in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, window, required

Hi im having trouble with how to user the super() keyword properly. It's a bit difficult to explain so please try to understand.

So I have a class called "Window" which is a subclass of another class called "Room".

This is `Room` class with a constructor

```
public class Room {

private Position position;

private Color color;

    public Room(Position pos, Color colour){
        this.position = pos;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

SO I want to give the doors a color `Color.RED` A Window object is constructed with an input position parameter.

What I have so far is:

```
public class Window extends Room{

private Color color;

    public Window(Position position, Color color) {
        super(position, color);
        this.colour = Color.RED;
    }
```

However in my other classes there is code that create a new `Window` with only a position parameter

This is `example` code

```
public class example{
private Window   window;
private Position position;

public example() {

}

@Before
public void create() {
    position = new Position(4,3);
    window = new Window(position);
}
```

So then it becomes a `required` and `found` error, telling me that the length is not right. I understand what the error is telling me.

So here is my question. How do I redo the `Window` constructor so that it will satisfy both the super class and my other classes without those classes being changed.

Comment: Why does `Window` have a field `color` when it's superclass `Room` also has a field `color`? How do you know which of the two colors to refer to? And - secondly - and this is perhaps causing this confusion: when B is a subclass of A, you can generally say "B is a A". But in your cause, Window is a subclass of Room. Except you can't say that "a Window is a Room". You may be using the wrong OO construct here.

Comment: As a general note, `Window` should not inherit from `Room`. See [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new constructor in Window and set default color.

```
public Window(Position position) {
        //Set default color
        super(position, Color.RED);
        this.colour = Color.RED;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another constructor to your `Window` class:

```
public class Window extends Room {

    public Window(Position position) {
        super(position, null);
    }
```

Alternatively, define a default color which gets passed instead of `null`.